# unable to control taskbar audio control with keyboard media keys

Tags: android, bluetooth, taskbar, audio-streaming

I am streaming music from phone to computer via bluetooth.  I have a bluetooth audio control in my taskbar that doesn't respond to windows media key commands - play/pause, next, prev.

any ideas on how I can control this player with my computer keyboard.  I am familiar with ahk.